# Every other frame corrupted when rendering with Adobe Media Encoder

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

I'm trying to render a video from Adobe Media Encoder, created in After Effects. We first had this problem is a larger file, so I reduced it down to a simple file the results of which can be seen in this gif.

[image: What the video comes out looking like]

Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

Specs:

- Media Encoder, 2015.4 Release, Build 10.4.0.26 (latest)
- After Effects, 2015.3 Release, Version 13.8.1.38 (latest)
- MacBook Pro Retina 15-in, Mid-2014, OS X 10.11.6 (latest) - 16 GB Ram, 2.5 GHZ i7
- Source Comp; px 1.0, 29.97 fps, Progressive
- Output, H.264 Match Source, High bitrate (VBR 1 pass)
- Also exported as PNG sequence but the corruption was still there

Comment: Turn off CUDA rendering, as per [here](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/18405/1871).

Comment: @Mulvya that was it! Thanks a bunch. You want to put that in an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [answered](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/18405/1871) in this Q/A, the problem looks to be caused by the use of the CUDA renderer ("Mercury"). The solution is to switch to CPU-only rendering.

Comment: This was it. In case anyone else can't find it it's in Media Encoder > Preferences. Change Video Rendering to “Mercury Playback Engine Software Only"